# Updating values in Sqlite of Android and ContentValues

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I want to update a row in a table, updating all the columns to new values except one that should keep the greatest value between the old and newValue.

Is there some way of doing this without creating the raw query (for example using the [`update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String\[\] whereArgs)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) function or other similar using ContentValues) in order to seize the character scaping and other advantages of that providers?

The query I want to achieve is something like:

```
UPDATE users SET name='newName', address='newAddress',
                 lastLogin=GREATEST(lastLogin,1348757941);
```

Comment: not that i know of. I don't think you can put functions in ContentValues (you can still try to put the string "max(something)" as you would in a rawQuery) or you can try to figure out something with the where clause. Can you post the rawQuery ?

Comment: I'd need a function in the ContentValues. Posted the raw query

Comment: I doubt you could put the max function is the contentValue, as the escaping is probably made to prevent things like that. I don't see a way of doing this without rawQuery (but i'm no expert in sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GREATEST` function is actually called [`MAX`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc):

```
UPDATE users
SET name = 'newName',
    address = 'newAddress',
    lastLogin = MAX(lastLogin, 1348757941)
```